# How to have a slack bot interact with a message and click an interactive button normally designated for human interaction

Tags: python, automation, slack, slack-api, interactive

My current set up is as follows:

- a message is sent once an hour to 'slack_channel_xyz'
- if that message contains certain content, a slack bot will create a message with two clickable options ('Verify' or 'Not Yet')
- the expected workflow is that normally a human will interact with one of those two buttons. Currently, when this button is clicked, everything works as expected with the callback (the buttons work, basically, and a submission is made to an external recipient)

The issue I am running into is that I would like to *automate* this submission process. During certain hours of the day, I would need for this 'Verify' button in the automated bot response to be clicked/invoked by an external Python process.

I can correctly identify the message in question. I can see the content, block_ids, action_ids, etc. (see below, obfuscated for privacy reasons)

```
{
  "bot_id": "##########",
  "type": "message",
  "text": "ARBITRARY_TEXT",
  "user": "##########",
  "ts": "1657662557.465969",
  "app_id": "##########",
  "team": "##########",
  "bot_profile": {
    "id": "##########",
    "deleted": "False",
    "name": "BOT_NAME",
    "updated": 1649356972,
    "app_id": "#########",
    "icons": {
      "image_36": "IMAGE_URL_36",
      "image_48": "IMAGE_URL_48",
      "image_72": "IMAGE_URL_72"
    },
    "team_id": "##########"
  },
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "block_id": "mSliR",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "text",
        "verbatim": "False"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "actions",
      "block_id": "blk_verify",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "button",
          "action_id": "OS7gz",
          "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Verify",
            "emoji": "True"
          },
          "style": "primary",
          "value": "g_approve"
        },
        {
          "type": "button",
          "action_id": "8nzm",
          "text": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Not Yet",
            "emoji": "True"
          },
          "style": "danger",
          "value": "FILE_URL"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the question is, given these parameters I can identify about the message, is there a way to programmatically (without human intervention) invoke the action that would be taken by clicking 'Verify' as though the button had been clicked by a human?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A Slack App can't click a button on a message, but you could *kind* of spoof it at least two other ways

- You could create a second slack app for the external process, and have that bot add a reacji to the message, which the original process could listen for.
- You could just take Slack out of the equation when the external process is involved and just create an API endpoint for the other process to hit

After either scenario, the Slack Bot would update the relevant message to remove the button, or whatever action you take when a human clicks it.